# OSDev - Can't access lfb with paging enabled

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, osdev

I'm trying to add VESA to JamesM's tutorial but I can't access the LFB when paging is enabled. It works fine when paging is disabled. I'm using napalms v86 hack to switch to VESA mode and it works great but I can't plot pixels while paging is enabled. By switching back to textmode it tells me that the lfb is located at `0xFD000000` but i also get an error:

`Page-fault! (present read-only ) at 0xFD01E078` why is that?

And can someone provide me with a sample on how i can map the lfb correctly. At the moment I just use this:

```
for (i = 0xFD000000; i < 0xFDFFFFFF; i += 0x1000)
        get_page(i, 1, kernel_directory);
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to map the lfb

Comment: There's no way to know what `get_page` does. Does it return a virtual address for requested physical page? Does it identity-map physical page to virtual address? I can only assume that the second parameter is setting page privileges, and therefore there should be `3` instead of `1` (second bit is the `RW` bit, which allows writes to the page). Try using `get_page(i, 3, kernel_directory)`, or just give us more information.

Comment: my code is actually just modified code from jamesm's tutorial found at:
"http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/6.-Paging.html" at the bottom you can download the source from each step. I wont post the get_page function. you can find it on the page :)

Comment: Did you correctly map it to that _physical_ location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_page(i, 1, kernel_directory);
```

Is declared as

```
page_t *get_page(u32int address, int make, page_directory_t *dir);
```

That means that it returns a pointer on a **page entry**, not on a page itself. Also, it doesn't create a new page entry if necessary, it only makes sure that a **page table** for a specific page exists.

```
unsigned int i;
for (i = 0xFD000000; i < 0xFE000000; i += 0x1000)
{
    page_t * pg = get_page(i, 1, kernel_directory); //get pointer on a page entry
    *pg = (page_t)(i | 0x3); //set that page entry to identity-map address stored in `i`, being it present and writable.
}
```